# Website giving pronunciations of English words recorded in different dialects?

Tags: pronunciation, dialects, accent, resources

I'm aware that there are certain websites around that provide recorded examples of English words pronounced in different accents/dialects.  Could anybody list some of them?

Comment: Note that any answers might want to include http://www.thefreedictionary.com which provides a US and a UK sound pronounciation of their words.

Comment: [Forvo](https://forvo.com/languages/en/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Oxford Dictionaries](http://english.oxforddictionaries.com/) has sound recordings of all its entries.

You might also like to explore these:

[Phonetics: The Sounds of Spoken Language](http://www.uiowa.edu/~acadtech/phonetics/)

[The Speech Accent Archive](http://accent.gmu.edu/browse_atlas.php)

[Sounds Familiar](http://www.bl.uk/learning/langlit/sounds/index.html) (from the British Library – for British accents)

Comment: Also to add to this list: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/ and http://www.forvo.com/ (thanks Cerberus!)

Answer (score 1):

Without question, [Accents of English from Around the World](http://www.soundcomparisons.com/) is the absolute best at all this. It provides both narrowly transcribed IPA and full sound recordings for around 40 different English dialects from all over the world.  However, it only covers about 130 different words. Still, that’s over 5,000 recordings, and one can infer many more. But it is a completely fascinating site, the best for this I’ve ever seen. And no, I have no connection with it.

That said, I wouldn’t believe the excruciatingly annoying ‘Valley-Guy teen’ rising intonation pattern for the putative speaker of General American, where every word (apart from *hundred*) has a perfect fourth ascending, no matter its stress pattern.  The Chicago version is much more normal in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

[EnglishLD community for English Learners](http://www.englishld.com)

Follow the link bellow, create an account and filt your vocabulary through dictation online. You can get pronunciation, definition, antonyms... of your words.