# What're websites I can search/request native speaker to speak some word?

Tags: pronunciation

I want to know good website that I can search or request native speaker to speak some word. I usually use [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com) but it has only once sound.

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/49764/website-giving-pronunciations-of-english-words-recorded-in-different-dialects

Comment: What kind of native speaker? British, American or Indian? Then do you want Scouse or Geordie, New England or Los Angeles?

Comment: @MartinBeckett I want to learn generic American accent. If you know some websites please tell me. :)

Answer (score 2):

A very interesting and very ambitious website (all the words in the world pronounced) is http://www.forvo.com.  A random search for the pronunciation of 'wuthering' yields three native speakers' pronunciations, two pronunciations of American English and one of British English, which gives you a good range of choices: http://www.forvo.com/word/wuthering/#en