# Is there a dictionary with phonemic transcription for different dialects?

Tags: dialects, dictionaries

Sometimes I am not sure how a Northerner says ***"Winter is coming"***.

I searched on the Internet but nothing showed up. I wonder if you know there is a dictionary (online or offline) that simply contains phonemic transcription for different English dialects.

Comment: Hello, bcelary. Requests for resources are off-topic on ELU, but this seems less unreasonable than most.

Comment: Your answer might be found here, at this possible dupe: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/49764/142429

Comment: Can't speak for all Northerners, but up here in Canada "Winter is coming" sounds a whole lot like "It's hockey season!" :P

Answer (score 0):

Not phonemic so much as phonetic.
Phonemic transcription is intended to level dialects, not to represent them.

A good starting source is the [*Dictionary of American Regional English*](http://dare.wisc.edu/).

Comment: Although, sometimes the differences between dialects are phonological rather than just phonetic (for example, the differences between American and British varieties), and leveling out phonological differences requires the use of "diaphonemic" transcription or lexical sets.